# How to get the vertex with the highest degree centrality in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I want to get the vertex with the highest degree centrality using `igraph`.

I tried the following code, but it doesn't return what I am expecting:

```
V(g)[degree(g,V(g)$id) == which.max(degree(g))]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(5)
g <- ba.game(100)
V(g)$id <- paste0("id", 1:100)
(idx <- which(degree(g)==max(degree(g))) )
V(g)$id[idx]
# [1] "id1" "id2"

# optional plot
cols <- rep("blue", vcount(g)); cols[idx] <- "red"; plot(g, vertex.shape="none", vertex.label.color=cols, edge.arrow.size=.5)
```

Comment: Good, it works.
After obtaining the id, how to get the vertex attribute (label for example).
this syntax doesn't work :
V(g)$label[which(V(g)$id==id)]

Comment: `V(g)$label[idx]`.

Answer (score -1):

```
V(g)$degree <- degree(g)

which.max(V(g)$degree)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?